# C# Windows.Media.Transcoding outputting video stream instead of a file

Tags: c#, windows, screen-capture, screensharing

I use C# to make a screen sharing program, refer to this script [SimpleRecorder](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/SimpleRecorder/). Utilizes [Windows.Graphics.Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture?view=winrt-22621)  and [Windows.Media.Transcoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.transcoding?view=winrt-22621).
This is the important part of the code of the Encoder class:

```
  private async Task EncodeInternalAsync(IRandomAccessStream stream, uint width, uint height, uint bitrateInBps, uint frameRate)
        {
            if (!_isRecording)
            {
                _isRecording = true;

                _frameGenerator = new CaptureFrameWait(
                    _device,
                    _captureItem,
                    _captureItem.Size);

                using (_frameGenerator)
                {
                    var encodingProfile = new MediaEncodingProfile();
                    encodingProfile.Container.Subtype = "MPEG4";
                    encodingProfile.Video.Subtype = "H264";
                    encodingProfile.Video.Width = width;
                    encodingProfile.Video.Height = height;
                    encodingProfile.Video.Bitrate = bitrateInBps;
                    encodingProfile.Video.FrameRate.Numerator = frameRate;
                    encodingProfile.Video.FrameRate.Denominator = 1;
                    encodingProfile.Video.PixelAspectRatio.Numerator = 1;
                    encodingProfile.Video.PixelAspectRatio.Denominator = 1;
                   
                    var transcode = await _transcoder.PrepareMediaStreamSourceTranscodeAsync(_mediaStreamSource, randomAccessStream, encodingProfile); 
                   await transcode.TranscodeAsync();
                }
            }
        }
   private void CreateMediaObjects()
        {
            // Create our encoding profile based on the size of the item
            int width = _captureItem.Size.Width;
            int height = _captureItem.Size.Height;

            // Describe our input: uncompressed BGRA8 buffers
            var videoProperties = VideoEncodingProperties.CreateUncompressed(MediaEncodingSubtypes.Bgra8, (uint)width, (uint)height);
            _videoDescriptor = new VideoStreamDescriptor(videoProperties); 
            // Create our MediaStreamSource
            _mediaStreamSource = new MediaStreamSource(_videoDescriptor);
            _mediaStreamSource.BufferTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
            _mediaStreamSource.Starting += OnMediaStreamSourceStarting;
            _mediaStreamSource.SampleRequested += OnMediaStreamSourceSampleRequested;

            // Create our transcoder
            _transcoder = new MediaTranscoder();
            _transcoder.HardwareAccelerationEnabled = true;
        }

    private void OnMediaStreamSourceSampleRequested(MediaStreamSource sender, MediaStreamSourceSampleRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (_isRecording && !_closed)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var frame = _frameGenerator.WaitForNewFrame())
                    {  
                        if (frame == null)
                        {
                            args.Request.Sample = null;
                            DisposeInternal();
                            return;
                        }

                        var timeStamp = frame.SystemRelativeTime;

                        var sample = MediaStreamSample.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(frame.Surface, timeStamp);
                        args.Request.Sample = sample;  
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                    Debug.WriteLine(e);
                    args.Request.Sample = null;
                    DisposeInternal();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                args.Request.Sample = null;
                DisposeInternal();
            }
        }
```

However, this code  `var transcode = await _transcoder.PrepareMediaStreamSourceTranscodeAsync(_mediaStreamSource, randomAccessStream, encodingProfile); await transcode.TranscodeAsync();` can only be stored in a file memory and does not allow me to send video streams in real time through UDP multicast.

I think I need to respond to an event after completing the encoding of a frame and obtain the byte[] of this frame.
I'm struggling because I don't have much experience with screen sharing.